# How to speedup Ant build process

Tags: ant

Earlier I used my local workspace to keep all the project contents. Now I moved that to a remote server. I just created empty folder (remote_ws) in my local PC and mount that with remote workspace (ws). Before I open eclipse giving following command in a terminal and then it will mount local workspace folder(remote_ws) and remote workspace folder(ws). By giving that command all the remote contents are available in local PC. 
Command is,

sshfs -o nonempty hera@192.168.1.83:/projects/project_hera/ws /external/remote_ws/

I am using [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) build to build this project. My problem is earlier it took around 2 minutes to build this project. But now it is taking very long time (around 15 minutes) to build the same project. To copy content to a mount local folder (remote_ws) is taking very long time.

How can I speedup this build process? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build (compilation, creation jar, war) etc involves a lot IO.  You cannot make it fast without improving over-all IO performance - faster disk, faster network etc.

Build will be faster on the machine where source code exist. I would advice to use a CI (say [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and do a build on the remote server. They can checkout, build , test and deploy without any manual intervention.